# Flutter including tflite version showing error

Tags: tensorflow, flutter, tensorflow-lite

> /.../flutter_linux_v1.7.8+hotfix.4-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/tflite-1.0.4/android/src/main/java/sq/flutter/tflite/TflitePlugin.java
>   uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with
>   -Xlint:unchecked for details.

I am continuously getting this error and i have tried all the version of Tflite till 1.0.1, but still getting the same error.

Comment: Does that crash your app or is it only a warning?

Comment: No that doesn't crash my app, but I am not able to use tflite feature in-app, @easeccy, please help!

Comment: That warning is not necessary. Your problem might be something else.